# Programmatically get localized user-friendly group policy names in Windows

Tags: c++, active-directory, wmi, group-policy, gpo

Please take a look at this screenshot (gpedit.msc) of local group policy settings on my computer:

[image]

Is there any way to retrieve user-friendly (localized) group policy names (circled in the screenshot above) from a C++ program (or maybe using WMI)?

Comment: @yesterday how do you include images like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Managing Group Policy ADMX Files Step-by-Step Guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709647%28WS.10%29.aspx) you can find, on your W2K8 server, in the file `C:\Windows\PolicyDefinitions\Desktop.admx` an XML description of what is circled in the screenshot above. You can link the description and help tag of this file with `C:\Windows\PolicyDefinitions\Desktop.adml` an XML-based ADM files that contain language-specific settings.

---

Edited

To parse XML in C++ I use to use these two libraries :

1. [XMLLite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163436.aspx)
2. [TinyXML](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/index.html)

Comment: Very nice, thank you. Now I need to figure out how to parse it out :)

Comment: Can it be considered as an answer ?

Comment: Yes, of course. Do you have any idea how to do the parsing? Maybe with WMI?

Comment: Here are two XML parser libraries.